# What are the applications of Zsigmondy's Theorem?

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, prime-numbers

I am referring to the theorem that, with some exceptions, $a^n\pm b^n$, $a,b,n\in\mathbb{N}$ has primitive prime divisors for every $n$. I have tried researching this myself, but have only seen vague statements on Wikipedia like "Zsigmondy's theorem is often useful, especially in group theory, where it is used to prove that various groups have distinct orders except when they are known to be the same." or papers that give applications to large Zsigmondy primes (https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1997-125-07/S0002-9939-97-03981-6/S0002-9939-97-03981-6.pdf).

Is there a clarification for the first point from wikipedia, and are there any famous applications of Zsigmondy's theorem I am missing here?

Comment: Check this article http://pommetatin.be/files/zsigmondy_en.pdf

Comment: This theorem is , for example , useful to bound the number of prime factors of a mersenne number and for informations which forms the prime factors can have.

Comment: `number-theory` and `elementary-number-theory` are almost mutually exclusive labels.

Comment: I would suggest searching for "Zsigmondy" in posts to MSE and MO with tag group-theory. You will find lots of applications that way.